# Error #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Tags: sql

EDIT - I am working in XAMPP

I'm doing a homework for school, and this is the database I'm given:

`customers(customerName, city, customerNumber)`

`orders(customerNumber, orderNumber)`

`orderdetails(orderNumber, priceEach, quantityOrdered)`

and I'm trying to query for the name of the customer who has placed the biggest order by total value (priceEach*quantityOrdered), and it's a requirement for me to use at least one nested query.

Here is what I *believe* should be the right answer:

```
SELECT customername
FROM orderdetails 
INNER JOIN orders
on orderdetails.orderNumber = orders.orderNumber
INNER JOIN customers
on orders.customerNumber = customers.customerNumber
WHERE sum(priceEach*quantityOrdered) = (SELECT 
    max(sum(priceEach*quantityOrdered))
    FROM orderdetails
    INNER JOIN orders
    on orderdetails.orderNumber = orders.orderNumber
    INNER JOIN customers
    on orders.customerNumber = customers.customerNumber
    GROUP by orderdetails.orderNumber)
GROUP by orderdetails.orderNumber
ORDER by sum(priceEach*quantityOrdered) DESC
```

However, when I enter it, I get an error "#1111 - Invalid use of group function" and I can't for the life of me figure out why.  Thanks

EDIT - even when I remove all the GROUP BY and ORDER BY lines from the query, I still receive the same error.  I *think* it has to do with me calling 'max' and 'sum' in the nested query SELECT but I am not totally sure.

Comment: the outer group by field should be also in select

Comment: Silly requirement, because that is not the best way to write the query.

Comment: that will be a good start.. checking for errors then checking the logic for the desired result :D

Comment: And what is the database you are in? MySql, Oracle, Postgresql, MSsql?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I already explained, it's a homework problem and the requirement is there to help us understand how nested queries work.

Comment: @Jorge Campus - XAMPP

Comment: Sorry for the delay... Just so you know, your database is MariaDB. XAMPP Is a package distribution that holds Apache, MariaDB (Former MySql), PHP and Perl and some other things. I will not provide a answer since the guys here already did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using GROUP BY, all the fields in SELECT must be in an aggregate function or included in the GROUP BY clause.

How about this:

```
SELECT customername, SUM(orderTotal)
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN (SELECT priceEach*quantityOrdered AS orderTotal, customers.customerNumber AS customerNumber
            FROM orderdetails 
            INNER JOIN orders 
            ON orderdetails.orderNumber = orders.orderNumber
            INNER JOIN customers ON orders.customerNumber = customers.customerNumber) sub 
            ON sub.customerNumber = customers.customerNumber
GROUP by customername
ORDER by SUM(orderTotal) DESC
```

Comment: Your comment is not saying that at all. customername he is selecting should  be in some aggregate function, or included in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Hi - thank you for this, but even when I remove all the GROUP BY and ORDER BY lines from the query, I still receive the same error.  I *think* it has to do with me calling 'max' and 'sum' in the nested query SELECT but I am not totally sure.

Comment: In your nested querry you are multiplying priceEach with quantityOrdered before aggregating them, and none of them is included in GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

> and it's a requirement for me to use at least one nested query.

the cross apply will get the max Sales with the customernumber to return back to the main query.

sales should be grouped by customernumber

```
SELECT
  customername, y.TotalSales
FROM customers a
cross apply
(
select top 1 x.TotalSales,x.customerNumber from
(SELECT
  SUM(priceEach * quantityOrdered) [TotalSales], c.customerNumber
FROM orderdetails
INNER JOIN orders
  ON orderdetails.orderNumber = orders.orderNumber
INNER JOIN customers c
  ON orders.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
GROUP BY c.customerNumber)
) x order by x.totalSales desc
) y on y.customerNumber = a.customerNumber
```

or for max at the order level, group by customernumber,ordernumber

```
SELECT
  customername, y.totalsales, y.ordernumber
FROM customers a
cross apply
(
select top 1 x.TotalSales,x.customerNumber,x.ordernumber from
(SELECT
  SUM(priceEach * quantityOrdered) [TotalSales], c.customerNumber,ordernumber
FROM orderdetails
INNER JOIN orders
  ON orderdetails.orderNumber = orders.orderNumber
INNER JOIN customers c
  ON orders.customerNumber = c.customerNumber
GROUP BY c.customerNumber,ordernumber)
) x order by x.totalSales desc
) y on y.customerNumber = a.customerNumber
```